# Using awk to detect // as an end of headers marker

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, awk

Currently I am parsing a script with the following command

ions and in the file it should only be from the first numeric (in this case five). The first file always start with the pattern `[numeric]`.

Just a quick further task: is there maybe some additional way to grep the numerics inh all these numbers in there in the same go?

Comment: maybe this is a bitr more clear?

Comment: @mat is that helkpful?

Comment: @mat that is a great answer is there maybe a way to create the foruth file as mentioned in the comment to you answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a very simple state machine - only two states: header or body.

```
curfile != FILENAME{body=0;curfile=FILENAME}
!body && /^\/\/$/    {body=1}
body  && /^\[/       {print > "first_"FILENAME}
body  && /^(seg|pos)/{print > "second_"FILENAME}
body  && /^[01]+/    {print > "third_"FILENAME}
```

This starts by setting `body` to zero/false whenever the filename changes (`curfile` will initially be unset), and switches that to one/true when the header separator is seen. The other rules only apply inside the body.

To extract the first bracketed number from the first group of lines, with this simple pattern you can just use the `substr` and `index` [string manipulation functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). Something like the following should do:

```
body  && /^\[[0-9]+\]/ {
  print > "first_"FILENAME
  print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-2) > "fourth_"FILENAME
}
```

Comment: You don't even have to set `body` to zero, a variable name of a variable that isn't (yet) set will default to false if interpreted as boolean.

Comment: @heinheo: you want the first `[number]` of each of those lines in a separate file, or all of the numbers between brackets?

Comment: @mat could you let me know how I could feed more than a single file into that framework at once...I know you use the filename option but where do I feed my list.txt in? In which list.txt containes the filenames fo all the files I want to parse?

Comment: If `list.txt` contains the names of the files you want to parse, the command syntax you have in your question already does what you want - the `$(<file.txt)` piece reads that file and expands to its contents. (will fail with filenames containing spaces.) or just list all your files individually or with a glob pattern at the end of the command. `awk -f script.awk file1 file2 file3 some*patter? ...`

Comment: Ah, sorry hadn't understood. See update, that should do the trick, @heinheo

Comment: @mat everything works excellent except for in the second file it shoudl start with the first number after pos: ...currently it starts with segsites then newline then pos and then only the number...can we fix that somhow?

Comment: @heinheo: yes you can fix that quite easily. If you don't want segsite printed, don't match on it. If you don't want the pos printed, use a substring or one of the tricks [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198138/printing-everything-except-the-first-field-with-awk)

Comment: @mat does that mean I would just write what instead of /^(seg|pos)/ ...I tried /^(pos)/ awk '{first = $1; $1 = ""; print $0, first; }' but that did not work

Comment: @heinheo: why are you trying to save the first item if you don't want it. `/^pos/{$1="";print > [...]`.

Comment: @mat could you maybe jsut potentially update if somebody comes accross as similar question?

Comment: @heinheo: it is extremely unlikely that someone with the exact same requirement comes along. My answer gives the general technique(s). I can't  list all awk functions and tools. If you need more processing on specific lines, search for the specific things you need for those lines.

Comment: @mat I added body  && /^pos/{$1="";print > "second_"FILENAME} as a second line in the file but now it does not work any more...is the } behind FILENAME incorrect?