# How to reverse order of columns in tabular data using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Given tabular output from some program in bash I would like to change order of colums printed. Assume number of columns might vary.

## Sample input

```
Name  Surname   Age
Oli   Aaa       15
Boa   Bbb       25
```

## Expected output

```
Age  Surname    Name
15   Aaa        Oli
25   Bbb        Boa
```

## What I tried

It seems to me as an easy task when number of columns is known, but I don't know what to do when number of columns is just N. For 3 columns simple AWK script would do:

```sh
cat table.txt | awk '{print $3 $2 $1}' > reversed_table.txt
```

It would be good to achieve this using only POSIX-compliant tools.

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem and let us know then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> using only POSIX-compliant tools

`awk` is [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

> but I don't know what to do when number of columns is just N

Now that's easy. So first, `awk` is really flexible. The `awk '{ i=5; print $i; }` will print the 5th column, just like that.

Second you can get the number of columns with `NF`.

Now, it's just writing a simple for loop and iterating from the NF to first argument and viola!

```
 awk '{ for(i = NF; i >= 1; --i) printf "%s", $i "\t"; printf "\n" }'
```

A bit better version without a trailing tabulator:

```
 awk '{ for(i = NF; i >= 1; --i) printf "%s", $i (i==1 ? "" : OFS); print ""; }'
```

Comment: maybe a style choice but why not `i>0` instead.  Also, `print ""` should do.  However, you'll have a dangling tabs at the end of lines.`printf "%s", $i (i==1?ORS:OFS)` is better.

Comment: FWIW I prefer `printf "%s%s", $i, (i>1?OFS:ORS)` - 2 strings so 2 `%s`s and the ORS coming after the OFS both just feel more "right".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Generic solution. Where we have 2 variables named `swap1` and `swap2`, in swap one mention keep mapping with swap2 eg--> we want to exchange 3rd field to 5th field AND 4th field with 6th field. Likewise we can have a number of digits in it(I have considered a scenario where we want to exchange 3rd field to 5th field AND 4th field to 6th field).

```
swap1 --> 3    4
          |    |
          |    |
          |    |
swap2 --> 5    6
```

Following is the code:

```
awk -v swap1="3,4"  -v swap2="5,6" '
BEGIN{  
  num=split(swap1,field1,",")
  num1=split(swap2,field2,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    array1[field1[i]]=i
  }
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i in array1){
      tmp=$field1[array1[i]]
      $field1[array1[i]]=$field2[array1[i]]
      $field2[array1[i]]=tmp
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file  | column -t
```

Comment: @Ed Morton, Hi Ed sir, I have come up with this generic approach(IMHO :) ), May I ask you your thought sir on same if you wouldn't mind sir, how it looks to you?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and rev):

```
sed 's/.*/echo "&" | rev/e;s/\S\+/$(echo "&"|rev)/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Reverse each line and re-reverse each separate word within the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{use = $NF;$NF = "";print use,$2,$1}' OFS="\t" file

Age Surname Name
15  Aaa     Oli
25  Bbb     Boa
```

I looked into this one:
[Printing everything except the first field with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198138/printing-everything-except-the-first-field-with-awk)